# Using Large Font and Buttons for WPF calendar

Tags: wpf, calendar

I need to provide large fonts for date numbers, month, Day-of-week headers and prev/next buttons for a WPF calendar. This is a touch-screen application with no mouse.

What is the ABSOLUTE SIMPLEST MINIMAL xaml code to do JUST this? I don't want pretty or clever. I just want BIG FONTS. Big enough for mechanics to locate and press on a grubby, dusty, grease-coated screen.

One thing I've tried is below. That didn't work. I don't understand it and don't want to. I don't have time to go chasing down all this template styling mishmash. Honestly what I'm after is for someone to just cook something up and give it to me. I'm running out of time, and I just want this thing in my rearview.

```
Style  TargetType="{x:Type Calendar}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Calendar}">
                    <CalendarItem x:Name="PART_CalendarItem"
                              Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                              BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                              BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"/>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="PART_CalendarItem" Property="Padding"  Value="0,0,0,0" />
                            <Setter TargetName="PART_CalendarItem"  Property="Background"   Value="Yellow" />
                        </Trigger>

                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried please so we can better assist you?

Comment: I edited and put in one of the many things I've tried. I've been at this one goofy task for hours and hours and hours, and I am sick of googling for it, only to get 500,000 lines of impenetrable gobbledygook that maps the human genome. I just want it done.

Comment: You could just magnify the lot. Stick it in a viewbox and set the size bigger.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see you changing the FontSize in the XAML you provided but no matter. I just tried it and it looks like the default template ignores it anyway. Probably the best approach then would be to redefine the Template but I agree, that could be a lot of initial work. I sympathize too... I have been where you are too and been just as frustrated (i.e. try making the scrollbar wider/taller than the default size, ugh!)

So, if all you need is to just make the control larger then a simple approach would be to add a Scale to the LayoutTransform. For example, to double the size try:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Calendar}">
    <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
        <Setter.Value>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="2" ScaleY="2"/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```